# How to store an Object containing Array-Objects in local Storage By JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, multidimensional-array, stringify

I have this Object containing pretty much anything i want to know about a workout. Yet when I Stringify the object the array-objects aren't stored or something.

This is my object i want to stringify:

```
Object {name: "testWorkout", program: Array[4]}
name: "testWorkout"
program: Array[4]
        first: Array[3]
        slope: 0
        speed: "medium"
        time: 10
        length: 3
        __proto__: Array[0]

        interval1: Array[4]
        radio: "Time"
        size: "33"
        slope: "79"
        speed: "fast"
        length: 4
        __proto__: Array[0]

        interval2: Array[4]
        radio: "Time"
        size: "3322"
        slope: "16"
        speed: "medium"
        length: 4
        __proto__: Array[0]

        last: Array[3]
        slope: 0
        speed: "medium"
        time: 20
        length: 3

    __proto__: Array[0]
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

But instead it stringifies nice it does stringify as:

```
{"name":"testesr","program":[null,null,null,null]}
```

How to solve this with pure JavaScript? So without JQuery?

These are my stringify and read method:

```
function putInLocalStorage(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(workout));
    localStorage.setItem('workout-'+workout.name, JSON.stringify(workout));
}

function readLocalStorage(){
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('workout-'+workout.name);
    console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your object looking as below then stringify. It should work.

```
Object {name: "testWorkout", program: {}}
```

Point here is normal `JavaScript` arrays are designed to hold data with numeric indexes. You can stuff named keys on to them but the `JSON` array data type cannot have named keys on an array.

Comment: I guess the same goes for all the other Arrays()? As I Can see the 2nd level intervals and warmup/cooldowns now :D!